# SQL Query Not Working - Not Picking Up Matching Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive been trying this query for half an hour - for some reason it only picks up the first row when I know that there are other rows that match the criteria. Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
SELECT  `res`.id,  `res`.time,  `res`.price,  `res`.ppl,  `res`.rest,  `city`.city
FROM  `res` 
JOIN  `city` ON  `res`.city =  `city`.id
WHERE  `res`.id >  '0'
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

Comment: Please set up a sqlfiddle with sample data. The problem is mostlikely the data doesn't fit the join - but we can't see that.

Comment: nope - there are rows with id 15, 16, 17, and 18, but the query only finds the id of 15.

Comment: sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a995/1

Comment: Records in res only has column city that '6' matched in table city.

Answer (score 0):

The data and the join don't match. There is only one city that will be returned with your query - joining res with city: city 6. and with that city there's only one res returned.